# Searching for an arbitrary cluster of Linked Nodes Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j.  I have setup a basic db with around 200 nodes, these are amongst others, people, addresses, and phone numbers.

They can all be linked to each other, so a person can have a phone number and address associated with them, but an address can be connected to a phone number, phone numbers can be linked to phone numbers, people to people, etc

I want to be able to search for a cluster of nodes, e.g. I want to return all nodes that are connected in anyway, where e.g.:

- One person has a surname of say james,
- Another person has a surname of jones,
- A phone number containing 123456
- An address with a postcode of AB11AB

For each of the above multiple results can be found, and I want to find a cluster(s) that links at least one of each of the above (to 1 level initially, but eventually configurable levels).  I don't care how they are linked as long as they are.

In addition there could be more than 4 items to search for (this is configured by the user).

I have tried searching for them individually, and then trying to UNION them, and COLLECT them together, but I can't seem to get the logic right.

Some simple queries that return related nodes (to get a feel for my data):

```
MATCH (p:person {Surname:"james"}) RETURN a

MATCH (a:address {Postcode:"ab11ab"}) RETURN p
```

Is this possible?

Any help would be welcomed.

Thanks,

Jon

Cluster might not be the best terminology, maybe Sub Graph??

Here is the scenario:

```
CREATE (I1:person {description:'John James', FirstName:'John', Surname:'James'})
CREATE (I2:address {description:'1 Test Street ab11ab', Postcode:'ab11ab'})
CREATE (I3:contact {description:'01234567890 home telephone', Contact:'01234567890'})


CREATE (I4:person {description:'Frank James', FirstName:'Frank', Surname:'James'})
CREATE (I5:contact {description:'01234567899 home telephone', Contact:'01234567899'})


CREATE (I6:person {description:'Bert James', FirstName:'Frank', Surname:'James'})
CREATE (I7:person {description:'Brenda James', FirstName:'Brenda', Surname:'James'})
CREATE (I8:person {description:'Violet James', FirstName:'Violet', Surname:'James'})

CREATE (I9:address {description:'75 Test Street ab11ab', Postcode:'ab11ab'})

CREATE (I1)-[:LinkedTo]->(I2)
CREATE (I2)-[:LinkedTo]->(I3)

CREATE (I4)-[:LinkedTo]->(I5)

CREATE (I6)-[:LinkedTo]->(I7)
CREATE (I7)-[:LinkedTo]->(I8)

CREATE (I7)-[:LinkedTo]->(I9)
```

If I run the following:

```
MATCH (p:person)--(a:address)--(c:contact) 
    where p.Surname = "James"   AND 
          a.Postcode = "ab11ab" AND 
          c.Contact =~ "0123.*"  
RETURN p,a,c
```

I get the cluster I want.  However if I change the order of the links:

```
MATCH (p:person)--(c:contact)--(a:address) 
    where p.Surname = "James"   AND 
          a.Postcode = "ab11ab" AND 
          c.Contact =~ "0123.*"  
RETURN p,a,c
```

I get nothing.

What I am asking is I know the person, and contact, and address, do they link in any way?

Comment: Can you define more precisely the concept of cluster? With the example of test input data and the desired results?

Comment: Made changes to original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you should get an array of required nodes and then to find all paths connecting everyone with everyone.

```
// Get an array of all matching nodes:
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:person {Surname: "James"})
    WITH COLLECT(p) AS  c1
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:address {Postcode:"ab11ab"}) 
    WITH COLLECT(a)+c1 AS c2
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:contact) WHERE c.Contact =~ "0123.*" 
    WITH COLLECT(c)+c2 AS nodes
// Take the Cartesian product:
UNWIND nodes AS n1
  UNWIND nodes AS n2
      // Get path:
      MATCH p = (n1)-[*]-(n2) 
          WHERE ANY(n IN nodes WHERE n IN NODES(p) AND NOT n IN [n1,n2])
RETURN p
```

Comment: With a set of 300 nodes the above took 10 minutes+ to run before I stopped it.  Altering the match section to use [*..2] seems to speed it up, but i'm losing accuracy.  Any suggestions?  My productions system will have 500,000+

Comment: You can try `shortestPath` function.

Answer (score 0):

These queries might get you started.

*Aside: I would recommend that you use different relationship types (like `HAS_ADDRESS`, `HAS_CONTACT`, and `KNOWS`) for the different kinds of relationships. This will make your queries easier to understand, and can eventually help you speed up your queries (because you can then simplify them).*

1. To find any person with the surname "James" who is connected in any way to a contact that starts with "0123":

   ```
   MATCH path=(p:person)-[*]-(c:contact) 
   WHERE
     p.Surname = "James"   AND 
     c.Contact =~ "0123.*"
   RETURN p,c
   ```
2. To find any person with the surname "James" who is connected in any way to a contact that starts with "0123", as long as the path between them includes an address whose postcode is "ab11ab":

   ```
   MATCH path=(p:person)-[*]-(c:contact) 
   WHERE
     p.Surname = "James"   AND 
     c.Contact =~ "0123.*" AND
     ANY(n IN NODES(path)[1..-1] WHERE
       'address' IN LABELS(n) AND n.Postcode = "ab11ab")
   RETURN p,c
   ```
3. To find any person with the surname "James" who is connected in any way to an address whose postcode is "ab11ab", as long as the path between them includes a contact that starts with "0123":

   ```
   MATCH path=(p:person)-[*]-(a:address) 
   WHERE
     p.Surname = "James"   AND
     a.Postcode = "ab11ab" AND
     ANY(n IN NODES(path)[1..-1] WHERE
       'contact' IN LABELS(n) AND n.Contact =~ "0123.*")
   RETURN p,a
   ```
4. To find any person with the surname "James" who is connected in any way to an address whose postcode is "ab11ab" AND a contact that starts with "0123" (this is likely to be slow with a large DB):

   ```
   MATCH (p:person {Surname: "James"})
   OPTIONAL MATCH path1 = (p)-[*]-(c:contact) 
   WHERE c.Contact =~ "0123.*"
   WITH p, c,
     [n IN NODES(path1)[1..-1] WHERE 'address' IN LABELS(n) AND n.Postcode = "ab11ab"] AS addrs
   OPTIONAL MATCH path2 = (p)-[*]-(a:address) 
   WHERE a.Postcode = "ab11ab"
   WITH p, c, addrs + a AS addrs,
     [n IN NODES(path2)[1..-1] WHERE 'contact' IN LABELS(n) AND n.Contact =~ "0123.*"] AS conts
   WITH p, addrs, conts + c AS conts
   UNWIND conts AS cont
   WITH p, addrs, COLLECT(DISTINCT cont) AS conts
   WHERE SIZE(conts) > 0
   UNWIND addrs AS addr
   WITH p, conts, COLLECT(DISTINCT addr) AS addrs
   WHERE SIZE(addrs) > 0
   RETURN p, conts, addrs
   ```